# Azure stuck on Adding Application setting

Tags: azure

I am logged in on https://portal.azure.com. I clicked on the "Web App Settings" of my application and tried to set the application setting. I can not add new application settings. I further investigated and it looks like i can only not set attributes that were defined in my web.config file before publishing. e.g.
My web.config contains "UserName" setting.
In App Setting on portal, i can add "UserNam" or "UserNamee" but i can not add "UserName" in the App Setting because it is already in web.config.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh the webpage and try again.